# CME error following HR2 hotfix rollup installation

Tags: 2011, cme

We have just installed the HR2 hotfix rollup onto our Tridion Content Manager servers. These servers were previously running SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

We have upgraded the CM database and completed the installation on the CM servers. Now when I try and access the CM Explorer in a browser, I see the following error. The CM Explorer doesn't load the list of publications, and throws the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

We are also seeing the following error in the event logs on the CM Servers:

```
A method call to an object in a COM+ application was rejected because the caller is not properly authorized to make this call. The COM+ application is configured to use Application and Component level access checks, and enforcement of these checks is currently enabled. The remainder of this message provides information about the component method that the caller attempted to invoke and the identity of the caller.Svc/Lvl/Imp = 10/6/1,  Identity = <Username>
```

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Has the installer reset some of the DCOM configuration settings, or bindings, or has something not been restarted correctly?

Both CM servers have been rebooted following the installation.

Comment: In the components snap-in right-click on Computer, choose Properties. Then select the COM Security tab is your account is allowed to access the components?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes. The Access Permissions and Launch and Activation permissions are identical to another CM server which is working correctly.

Comment: What is the OS on both of your servers? Also, did you try rebuilding the user profile for the user set as the user in Identity tab of the COM+ application.

Comment: The OS on all servers is Windows Server 2008 R2. How would we go about rebuilding the user profile?  The same service account is specified for both servers, and works fine on the other server.

Comment: Interestingly... when I get the screenshot as per the original post when loading the CME, if I then right click where the list of publications should be, and select refresh, the list of publications does then load. I can then browse through the CME and open pages and components successfully, although each time I do open something, I get the 404 non found error popup again.

Comment: Noting you say "Both CM servers" - can you confirm if the 404 is coming from one of the servers and the 'occasional' load from the other? What can you see from the 'Network' tab in firebug?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had a similar problem after install HR1 and HR2 on Tridion 2011 SP1.

After checked granted permissons of MTSUser on %TRIDION_HOME% I realised that this user lost their priveleges. After granting tridion works fine again.

Hope this helps!